# Redis data is getting deleted in docker after restarting my spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, redis, docker-compose

When i'm restarting my spring boot application all stored data is getting deleted,keys also not there  When I'm running this application locally data is not deleting but In docker after restarting server its behaving in create mode.

**This is my .yml file**

```
services:
    chat:
      container_name: chat
      build: .
      ports: 
          - 8888:8888
          - 4000:4000
      depends_on:
          - redis_chat

    redis_chat:
      container_name: redis_chat
      ports:
       - "6380:6379" 
      image: "redis:4.0.9"
      volumes:
        - ./redis-data:/var/data          
volumes:
  redis-data: {}
  db-data:``
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try deleting the volumes part. The redis service does not need it. It stores it automatically. See the example of sample redis service:

```
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.9
    container_name: example-redis
    hostname: example-redis
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```